# Noticeable increase in Surgequeuelength and SpilloverCount metrics for Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, istio, istio-gateway

I am using istio and I have karpenter setup. for node autoscalilng. I have couple of services running and Im using isito gateway. istio creates a classic load balancer in aws when setting up gateway-controller.

but now I am facing this issue. in the lb created I have 2 availability zones. eu-west-1a and eu-west-1b. the lb on eu-west-1a my Surge queue length is almost at 1024. the targets of this availability zone also looks good

any idea why this could be happening and is there a solution i can take for this ? below is how the service looks like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-ingress
  uid: 2d4d3df0-0ccd-42b3-a09b-2d3bfc51a1e6
  resourceVersion: '25530105'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-05-12T12:27:20Z'
  labels:
  ...
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: istio-ingressgateway
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-ingress
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '3600'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: >-
      arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:certificate/CERT_ID
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
  finalizers:
    - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  managedFields:
    - manager: terraform-provider-helm_v2.9.0_x5
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-05-12T12:27:20Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        ....
        f:spec:
          f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
          f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:ports:
            .: {}
            k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
            k:{"port":443,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
            k:{"port":15021,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:name: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:sessionAffinity: {}
          f:type: {}
    - manager: aws-cloud-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-05-12T12:27:22Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:finalizers:
            .: {}
            v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      subresource: status
    - manager: kubectl-patch
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2023-07-21T02:50:08Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: {}
            f:service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {}
            f:service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: {}
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-ingress/services/istio-ingressgateway
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: HOSTNAME.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
spec:
  ports:
    - name: status-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15021
      targetPort: 15021
      nodePort: 30938
    - name: http2
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 32121
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      nodePort: 32578
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  clusterIP: 172.20.23.186
  clusterIPs:
    - 172.20.23.186
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```